# Не получается залит коммит на гит

Tags: git

Изучаю гит. Создал репозиторий, залил коммит на ветку master

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем создал ветку dev и попытался тот-же коммит залить на ветку dev, но не получилось

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

кто знает причину?

Comment: Что пишет `git branch -a`?

Comment: * master
remotes/or/master
remotes/or2/master
коммит or я создавал до этого

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: локальную ветку dev вы таки **не** создали (и не сделали её текущей).

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout -b dev // создаст и переключит на новую ветку
git add .
git commit -m "Comments here"
git push origin dev // отправит изменения на удаленный репозиторий
```